# jump to specific id after php validation fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, scrolltop

could anybody advise me how I can let page jump (or scroll) to specific id, where error message appears after php validation fails ?

I have a php page which is long that user has to scroll to the bottom. In the middle of the page, there is contact form where user can input email address and comment. After user press "send" button, php validation works. However, it jumps to very top of the page after pressing "send" button. Afterwards, I can see error message shown just below the contact form by scrolling down by myself. But, it's not the way how it should be as you all would agree...

Then, I tried to use javascript scrollTop as it's shown below. ScrollTop works, although there is no error message appearing....

I know that I am missing something, but I don't know what I am missing....

Could you please help me ?

index.php and top.js are shown below;

index.php

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['sendemail'])){

  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['message'] = $_POST['message'];

  if (!$_SESSION['email'] || !filter_var($_SESSION['email'],    FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'please type correct email address';
  }

  if (!$_SESSION['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'please type message';
  }

  if (!$errEmail　&& !$errMessage) {
    header('Location: messagesent.php');
    exit;
  }
}
?>

<html>
  <head>..</head>
  <body>
    ...

   <section id="contact">
    ...
      <div>
        <input name="email" type="text">
        <label>Email</label>
        <?php echo "<p style='color:red;'>$errEmail</p>";?>
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <label>Message</label>
        <?php echo "<p style='color:red;'>$errMessage</p>";?>
      </div>
      <div class="right-align">
        <button id="contactbutton" type="submit" name="sendemail">Send</button>
      </div>
   ...
  </section>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/top.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

top.js

```
$(function(){
  $('#contactbutton').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a form element enclosing your inputs, you can set the form action to your current page using a fragment identifier:

```
<form action="#errors"> ... </form>
```

Then you can either assign an id to the error container:

```
<div id="errors">Error list</div>
```

Or place an empty anchor right before the error container:

```
<a name="errors"></a>
<div>Error list</div>
```

The name and id values must be unique in the document. No explicit redirection is needed.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can create an id for your message box:

```
<?php echo "<p id=\"errMessage\" style='color:red;'>$errMessage</p>";?>
```

then in your validation you can do something like:

```
if (isset($errMessage) && !empty($errMessage)) {
    header("Location: index.php#errMessage");
  }
```

This will focus the cursor on the error message. You can also use the same technique to change focus on the text area and other fields that is required.

Comment: Thanks mdodong for giving me an advise, I believe that your solution works as well, however adriann's solution is simpler to me as I am very much beginner of coding ...